# I've installed PyTorch, but CUDA is not recognized

Tags: python, pytorch

I installed [PyTorch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyTorch) using this command:

```
pip3 install torch===1.2.0 torchvision===0.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

And it seemed to work. When importing torch, there isn't any error. 
My laptop has a [GeForce 1060 TI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_10_series#GeForce_10_(10xx)_series), which I assumed would work with CUDA.

Here is the error in the IDE (Eclipse):

[image: Screenshot with code]

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should include code, not a graph!**

Remove PyTorch and install it again with this command:

```
conda install pytorch -c pytorch
pip3 install torchvision
```

after this try checking it with this command:

```
import torch
import torchvision
train_on_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()

if train_on_gpu:
    print('CUDA is available, Training on GPU ...')
else:
    print('CUDA is not available!  Training on CPU ...')
```